# Identify the three types of flow of control that can express any algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Identify the three types of flow of control that can express any algorithm?
Does anybody know this?

Comment: theoretically you could do any algorithm (i think) with just function calls kinda like lambda calculus

Comment: Have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com)?

Comment: IIRC - they're called sequence, selection and iteration (and has something to do with Michael Jackson [not the performer])

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you mean: sequence, branch (if-else), and loop (while)

Comment: Branch and loop, for sure. I was thinking sequence for the third, too, but it doesn't really strike me as "flow of control" so much as the lack thereof.

Comment: Ah, I see. According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Low-level_structure_programming), those are probably the idioms being referred to. On the other hand, at the lowest level, it's pretty much just gotos and stack manipulation.

Comment: @jpm - Anyone who ever microprogrammed a computer will tell you that sequential execution of instructions isn't something that just happens. It just happens to be the default flow of control, so you don't usually think too much about it (except, say, when you need to initialize a variable before you use it :)). OP is probably interested in _structured_ control flow, which excludes GOTOs.